# Kotlin way to create factories of generic classes

Tags: kotlin

I created this example:

```
fun main() {
 val (proc, msg) = ProcessorsFactory().getProcessor("A")
 val worker = Worker(proc,msg)
}

class ProcessorsFactory() {
    fun getProcessor(name: String): Pair<Processor<out Message>, Message>  {
        if (name == "A") {
            return Pair(AProcessor(),AMessage())
        }
       throw Exception("exception")
    }
}

class Worker<M : Message, P : Processor<M>>(
    private val processor: P,
    private val msg: M) {
    
}
    
class AProcessor: Processor<AMessage>() {}

class AMessage : Message() {}

abstract class Processor<M : Message> {
    fun processMessage(message: M) {
        println("message processed")
    }

}

abstract class Message {}
```

I would like to create a class ProcessorsFactory that produces for me object of classes that implement abstract class Processor and abstract class Message.
Next I want to use these objects in Worker class.

The problem that I get is from line:
`val worker = Worker(proc,msg)`

**Type mismatch: inferred type is Message but CapturedType(out Message) was expected
Type mismatch: inferred type is Processor but Processor was expected**

Could you help me to modify ProcessorsFactory() to return objects that I can use in Worker class?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in your code.

Your main problem, the one you asked about, is caused by the fact that after storing the message and processor in separate variables, both generic, the compiler can no longer ensure they use matching `M`. To ensure they match, the compiler would have to track both `proc` and `msg`, find all places where they are created, analyze the `getProcessor()` deeply and realize they always match. This is much more complicated than compilers usually do.

The easiest way to fix the problem is by creating some kind of a container for both objects and make the container itself also generic. This way we can easily proof both objects use the same `M`:

```kotlin
class Worker<M : Message, P : Processor<M>>(...) {
    constructor(procAndMsg: ProcessorAndMessage<M, P>): this(procAndMsg.processor, procAndMsg.msg)
}

data class ProcessorAndMessage<M : Message, P : Processor<M>>(
    val processor: P,
    val msg: M,
)
```

Another problem in your code is that your try to return `Processor<Message>` from the `getProcessor()`. This is a misconception about generics. `Processor<Message>` means the processor can handle any possible message. But we returned `AProcessor` which can handle `AMessage` only, so representing it as `Processor<Message>` is conceptually wrong, it is not type-safe. Instead, we should say the processor can handle some subtype of `Message`, but we don't know which one. We can do this using the star projection: `Processor<*>`.

By applying both above fixes, we get this:

```kotlin
fun getProcessor(name: String): ProcessorAndMessage<*, *>  {
    if (name == "A") {
        return ProcessorAndMessage(AProcessor(), AMessage())
    }
    throw Exception("exception")
}
```

BTW, please don't randomly add `out`/`in` just to force your code to compile. `Processor` obviously consumes messages, so it should be actually contravariant: `Processor<in M : Message>`. I suppose you added `out` only to force your incorrect code to compile: `return Pair(AProcessor(),AMessage())`. By doing this you don't fix the problem, but actually move it into another place and obfuscate what's the real problem.

`main()` in our example becomes:

```kotlin
val procAndMsg = ProcessorsFactory().getProcessor("A")
val worker = Worker(procAndMsg)
```

Also, I'm not exactly sure what is the context of your problem, it feels pretty strange that the processor factory returns a message. Anyway, as we can see, our `ProcessorAndMessage` is actually very similar to `Worker`. And that suggests another solution: maybe you should additionally return the `Worker` from the factory?  Maybe you should not at all return the message and processor, but only the worker? This is a common pattern that one code fragment knows a family of classes (`AMessage`, `AProcessor`, maybe `AWorker`), it constructs the whole object graph of matching objects (so it is type safe), and then we use them together as a "package" - we no longer care about their families.

Answer (score 0):

Take this with a grain of salt, since I can't fully know why you are doing what you are doing but what you need is [star-projection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#star-projections).

> For Foo<out T : TUpper>, where T is a covariant type parameter with the upper bound TUpper, Foo<*> is equivalent to Foo<out TUpper>. This means that when the T is unknown you can safely read values of TUpper from Foo<*>.

The key part is "This means that when the T is unknown you can safely read values of TUpper from Foo<*>"

```
class Worker<M : Message, P : Processor<*>>(
    private val processor: P,
    private val msg: M
)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define your `Worker` class as you have, namely:

```
class Worker<M : Message, P : Processor<M>>(
    private val processor: P,
    private val msg: M
)
```

you are prescribing that the `processor` parameter accepts `Message` instances of the same type `M` that the `msg` parameter is. Makes sense if you expect `msg` to be later processed by `processor`.

However, your `ProcessorsFactory` signature is:

```
fun getProcessor(name: String): Pair<Processor<out Message>, Message>
```

This promises to return a `Processor` and a `Message` pair, but it does not promise that that `Processor` will accept that type of `Message`, merely that it accepts some specific and unknown subtype of `Message`. This is the source of your errors.

You need to change the signature of `getProcessor` to ensure that the `Message` types relevant to each item in the `Pair` match. For instance, this would work, and clears your errors:

```
fun getProcessor(name: String): Pair<Processor<AMessage>, AMessage>
```

where the signature declares both items in the `Pair` use the type `AMessage`.

Other possibilities are weakening the requirements of the `Worker` constructor or giving `getProcessor` a generic parameter (though in the latter case you'd need to have a way to determine what that parameter was when calling the function).

The most appropriate solution depends, of course, on what you are precisely trying to achieve.